# Naming drop down inside a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have this inside my `<table>` and the naming inside my `addFields()` function does not seem to work... Does anyone know what alternative line of code do I need for this `document.getElementById('materials') += "<name='"+iteration2+"'>";`?

HTML:

```
<td>
    <p id="addFields">
        <input type="number" required name="productquantity1" min="1" max="1000">
        <select name="productline1" id="materials">
            <option value="123">123</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</td>
<td valign="top">
    <button type="button" onclick="addFields();">+</button>
</td>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var counter = 2;
    function addFields() {
        var iteration2 = "productline" + counter;

        var select = document.getElementById('materials').cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById('materials') += "<name='"+iteration2+"'>"; //does not work
        document.getElementById('addFields').appendChild(select);
        counter++;
    }
```

Comment: what are your trying to do?

Comment: There is an add button when clicked, it adds new drop down and I am trying to get the values of the newly added drop down in my servlet with request.getParameter();

Comment: And what makes you think that is done via a `<name>` _element_ …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply,
`select.name = iteration2;`

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, you should be doing:

```
document.getElementById('materials').innerHTML += "<name='"+iteration2+"'>";
```

You were adding a string to the element itself. Use [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/innerHTML) to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

use [setAttribute](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp)

```
var counter = 2;
function addFields() {
    var iteration2 = "productline" + counter;

    // clone select tag
    var select = document.getElementById('materials').cloneNode(true);
    // change cloned tag name
    select.setAttribute ('name', iteration2); 
    // add to parent
    document.getElementById('addFields').appendChild(select);

    counter++;
}
```